# Custom reference naming convention in ormlite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to change the default ***{PropertyReference}Id*** naming convention for references and foreign keys ?

For example, I want to do this :

```
public class Customer
{
    [References(typeof(CustomerAddress))]
    public int Id_PrimaryAddress { get; set; } // with a prefix

    [Reference]
    public CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

instead of that :

```
public class Customer
{
    [References(typeof(CustomerAddress))]
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; } // standard

    [Reference]
    public CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the code convention of [OrmLite's Reference Conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions) globally, but you can use the `[Alias("DbColumnName")]` to map it to a different underlying RDBMS Table column.

#### Overriding Conventions with Attributes

You're also able to use the [Foreign Key and References Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#foreign-key-and-references-attributes) as your example does to override the conventions, e.g. you can [play with this Live Example on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=92a3f007e3f5d5b3440408f849b5d0b0):

```
public class CustomerAddress 
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(CustomerAddress))]
    public int Id_PrimaryAddress { get; set; } // with a prefix

    [Reference]
    public CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}

db.CreateTable<Customer>();
db.CreateTable<CustomerAddress>();

var customer = new Customer
{
    Name = "The Customer",
    PrimaryAddress = new CustomerAddress {
        Address = "1 Home Street",
        Country = "US"
    },
};

db.Save(customer, references:true);
```

Where you can load it and its references and view it with:

```
var c = db.LoadSelect<Customer>(x => x.Name == "The Customer");

c.PrintDump();
```

Which will output:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: The Customer,
        Id_PrimaryAddress: 1,
        PrimaryAddress: 
        {
            Id: 1,
            Address: 1 Home Street,
            Country: US
        }
    }
]
```